Shape Key not working correctly in GLTF export
I've got a character imported into blender via the Character Creator importer (https://github.com/soupday/cc_blender_tools/releases/tag/2_0_9). Everything works fine in blender when changing the values:
 

 
but once exported to GLTF the results are different.
 

 
Any idea what might be happening? If I uncheck the 'Shape Keys Drive Jaw Bone' and import my character, the mouth shapes seem to break in the same way the GLTF export does. My blender knowledge is very rusty so hoping it might be something simple! Feels like I need to somehow preserve the link between the bone and the blendshape?
Update: The same issue happens when exporting FBX and importing in Unity and trying to adjust the blend shapes.
